# What is special about `PATH` with respect to the rest of the environment and sudo?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, path

From [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400598/156458)

> it's in fact possible to have `sudo` use the current
>   `PATH` (with the `env` command) and/or the rest of the environment
>   (with the `-E` option) just by invoking it right:
>
> ```
> sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
> ```
>
> In fact, one can make an alias out of it:
>
> ```
> alias mysudo='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'
> ```
>
> (It's also possible to name the alias itself `sudo`, replacing the
>   original `sudo`.)

Why is it to have `sudo` use the current `PATH` with the `env` command, instead of  the `-E` option?

Why is it to have `sudo` use the rest of the environment with the `-E` option, instead of the `env` command?

Is it correct that `PATH` is part of the environment?

What is special about `PATH` with respect to the rest of the environment?

Thanks.

---

From [sudo manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html)

> sudo tries to be safe when executing external commands.
>   To prevent command spoofing, sudo checks "." and "" (both denoting
>   current directory) last when searching for a command in the user's
>   PATH (if one or both are in the PATH). Note, however, that **the actual
>   PATH environment variable is not modified and is passed unchanged to
>   the program that sudo executes.**

Does it mean that the user's `PATH` is passed unchanged to the command which `sudo` executes, by "the actual PATH environment variable is not modified and is passed unchanged to the program that sudo executes"?

Comment: sudo handles PATH specially because otherwise you could trick sudo into running your version of some command with elevated privileges. So PATH is special in sudo, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `env_reset` is enabled (which it is, by default), `sudo` clears out the environment, and in particular provides its own `PATH` (see `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`). If `env_reset` is disabled, `env_check` and `env_delete` still apply, and `PATH` is still likely to be cleared. You can see this in action by comparing the output of

```
echo $PATH
```

and

```
sudo printenv PATH
```

If you have a customised `PATH`, you won’t see it in the output of `sudo printenv`.

The `env` trick works around the environment clean-up:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" command
```

asks `sudo` to run `env "PATH=$PATH" command`, with `$PATH` expanded by your shell to contain your current `PATH`; `env`, running as root, then stores the given value of `PATH` in its environment and runs `command` with that environment.

So `PATH` isn’t special, except in the context of `sudo`, depending on your configuration. Any variable can be made “special” in the same way by configuring `sudo` appropriately, and `PATH` can be made “unspecial” too. See the [`sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html) and [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html) manpages for details.

Comment: Thanks. Does the manpage of `sudo` mean that the user's `PATH` is passed unchanged to the command which `sudo` executes, by "the actual PATH environment variable is not modified and is passed unchanged to the program that sudo executes"? See my update.

Comment: Right, that part’s a bit confusing. `sudo` applies the settings from `sudoers`, including `PATH` processing if `env_reset` is enabled (and in various other cases), as described in the `sudoers` documentation; then it processes `PATH` in the way described in the `sudo` documentation. The part about passing `PATH` unchanged only applies to the last part of the processing: if `PATH` survives `sudoers` with `.` or an empty entry, `sudo` will process those last, but it won’t change `PATH` at that point to reflect that new order.

Comment: Thanks. From your comment, it seems to me that the environment list is set up before `sudo` forks a child process to execute a command, and then the child process inherits and then passes the environment list without change to the command.  From the manpage of `sudo`, "When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution
environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in
the child process", does it mean that environment list is set up in the child process, instead of the process which runs `sudo`?

Comment: What practical difference does it make? The environment is just an array of strings which is given as one of `execve`’s parameters. `sudo` doesn’t change its own environment, it builds a new array of strings to use when calling `execve`. It doesn’t matter whether that happens before or after `fork`.

Comment: Thanks. Why "If env_reset is disabled, env_check and env_delete still apply, and PATH is still likely to be cleared"?

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what I meant by that now, I need to check again...